# Which device we can use in place of relay for 35000 volt?

Tags: voltage, electronics, electrical-engineering

What can we use in place of relay for very high voltage and current supply switching (let's say 35000 volt).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

There are solid state high voltage switches, made by several companies. Have a look, for example, at [Silicon Power](https://siliconpower.com/solid-state-switches/), in particular their [Model S33A](https://siliconpower.com/datasheets/solidstateswitches/Model%20S33A%20Data%20Sheet%20March%202017.pdf) series. It handles up to 60kV, at up to 14,000A. Other suppliers offer even higher ratings.

Search "ultra high voltage switch" for other suppliers. Note that I have never used any device like these. Hence I cannot recommend any particular model, nor can I comment on particular applications.